# API based on user IP address

Tags: php, api, security

I developed an API to get all the data.

The site do not have a user registration system or anything to identify the user making a call to the API. If I could identify the user making the call, whenever someone misuse or attack the API I could even ban his IP.

I'm thinking of generating an API key based on user IP or MAC address but is it safe to do so? Any other suggestions?

Comment: What's serving your backend? What does the API have access to?

Comment: You won't have access to the MAC address, so forget that. The IP address of a client is subject to change by ISP, or masking by routers with NAT or proxy servers so you can't rely on it being accurate. You'll need to think of something else.

Comment: @ChristianTernus backend is based on PHP, API only has access to get all posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you won't get the MAC address of the end-user. Even if you read the MAC address of incoming packets, you'll only get the MAC address of your router (which you definitely do not want to ban!)

User IPs are pretty easy to change and/or spoof (malware or confused-deputy Javascript, for example). Blocking those that make bad requests is still a good idea, but you definitely don't want to use them for authentication.

You should consider pretty much everything in an HTTP request (path, headers, and so on) attacker-controlled input and definitely not make authentication decisions based solely on information contained therein.

You mention you have a PHP backend. Why not build a system to generate API keys through that?

Comment: Assuming the PHP backend API isn't using UDP, the attacker won't be able to spoof the IP address beyond a SYN flood DOS attack.

Comment: Outside of a few _very_ interesting attacks on TCP sequence numbers, you're right, of course. However, it's easy to use malware on a compromised host to ask for an API key from a new IP -- botnets do it all the time. That's all I mean.

Answer (score 2):

it is absolutely wrong, you cannot get MAC address of the user, there is no way from JS/PHP

many users behind NAT will have the same IP address for you, so you will not be able to distinguish them

Answer (score 2):

You say there is no user registration system, then why would you generate an API key?

You can't have both worlds. Either the requests are anonymous, or the user registers, in which case you can provide an API key (better be using HTTPS so the keys aren't stolen), and possibly further limit by IP address range depending on your use case.

As others have answered, MAC addresses are only available on the same physical network. They do not go through routers, so they do not travel the Internet. You don't have access to anyone's MAC address outside of your physical network unless you have written a custom application that collects it (and those can be spoofed).

IP addresses can be dynamic, and some people share IP addresses based on geography, ISP, carrier, or business. Besides, many of us can easily change our IP address, so it's difficult to manage access by IP address.

There are some pitfalls and it takes extra time to manage a public API. You have to be willing to shut off an IP address or IP address range despite the fact that you may be blocking innocent and upstanding users at the same time as the abusers. If your application is free, it may give you more freedom since there is no expected level of service and no contract, but you may want to guard yourself with a legal agreement.

Many public APIs still track by IP address and implement tarpits to simply slow down requests from any IP address that seems to be abusing the system. This way, legitimate users from the same IP address can still carry on, albeit slower.

In general, if your service is popular enough that someone wants to attack it, that's usually a good sign, so don't worry about it too much early on, but do stay ahead of it. You don't want the reason for your application's failure to be because users got tired of waiting on a slow server.

Your other option is to have the users register, so you can block by credentials rather than IP address when you spot abuse.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to ban an IP address for many reasons. And anyways, a hacker can spoof IP addresses, so this technique is useless.

What you can do is throttle the API calls based on the IP. i.e. limit the numbers of calls per IP per second.

You might find this helpful: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2007/04/02/12-ways-to-limit-an-api/