# How to identify users in IOS

Tags: ios, security, apple-push-notifications

We are developing an app for IOS.

Is there anyway I can check that the "identifierForVendor" that the device sends me in it's first connection to my server is actually valid?

If there isn't a way, how can I make sure someone is not just sending POSTS to my server and so making me create Device DB Objects that don't really exist?

The only secure way I have found is:

1- Make the App ask for a Device Token to APNs
2- Send it on it's first connection to my server.
3- Check with APNs Feedback Service
4- If token is ok, create the Device DB Object and continue from there.

Apple should let you know some Device-Vendor Id in a communication between Apple and your server every time someone downloads an app.

Thank you.

Comment: Would be nice for tracking, but it doesn't seem like this is between Apple and your server. See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460878/api-based-on-user-ip-address/19461599#19461599

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to append the "identifierForVendor" with something you can identify from your app. For example, if you append an alphanumeric string that looks like this: "A1B2C3D4E5F6G7" to be "A1B2C3D4E5F6G7-fromMyApp", then there is no way for someone to know what the custom appended string is, unless they have access to your code.

Of course there are more complex solutions, if you are genuinely concerned of people going so far as to monitor traffic from your app just to find the string.

Comment: May as well make it a public API because anyone who wants the key will have it.

Comment: Thank you. We've considered this option, but
It's not what I'm asking for. 
The notification APNs solution is the winner so far, but it could reduce the amount of data collected from my users or make the app slower.

I guess we could make the Device Objects and mark them as NOT_VERIFIED, then use Feedback System to verify them.

It would be so easy for apple to give you the option to add a URL to your app configuration, and every-time someone downloads it, it hits you with a Device-App Id. This is why I thought it existed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that registering for remote notifications prompts the user if they want to allow remote notifications for the app. If they choose no, there is no token generated.

Besides, they can sniff the token off the wire. Do you plan on tracking abuse and blocking users based on their token? Do you know that some actions cause a new token to be generated, such as resetting the device?

You can generate a unique ID (UUID) or use `identifierForVendor`, and store it in the user's key store and use that to track by device. It's still anonymous, and resetting the device resets this, but if you're tracking abusers, you can block them and they have to reset their device to try it again. This isn't much different from an APN token. It can still be sniffed, and they can still reset it. But at least the user doesn't have to say yes to allowing remote notifications.

If you're sending any kind of token, you should use HTTPS (SSL/TLS), not to protect the user from themselves (they can still sniff the token by doing their own man in the middle attack unless you are verifying the identify of the server), but this is to protect people from malicious users on the same network. You don't want to block some innocent user because they happened to use your app on a public network and inadvertently shared their token.

Of course, if we're talking a jail-broken device, all bets are off.