# Android/PHP - Best way to synchronize local and remote databases

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, synchronize

I have an Android app that needs to receive some data from the webserver. I already got everything working, my question is.. What's the best way to synchronize data from the webserver if I'm always adding some data to it's remote database through a HTML form?

I thought of putting a timestamp, then I can receive the data with the timestamp, I would be able to compare the timestamps with each data entry from my Android app database, then, update or add the information to my local database.

What's the best way to do it? Should I put a timestamp to each entry I put in the remote and local server? If yes.. How does timestamp works in PHP(MySQL) and Android(SQLite)?

Thanks in advance! ;D

Comment: How real time does it need to be?

Comment: Doesn't need to be real time.. People will get my app from google play, then every time they open it, I want to check for new version of database

Comment: simple xml based web service ?

Comment: Simple web service using json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming the data is read-only to the application and only changes on the server.

Here's how we do something similar:

The application passes up a "last_sync_date" to the server. If the last_sync_date is null, the server passes back all data.

The server always passes back a last_sync_date back to the application. The last_sync_date is in UTC server time. The application stores the last_sync_date.

Obviously, last_sync_date will be null the first time the app sends it, so the first time, it gets all data. From then on, it only gets new data.

Yes, a timestamp on each entry is used to determine which records are new/modified.

If need be, add a deleted column to each entry to "delete" them.

Comment: Very Nice! Thank you Marcus Adams! Like I said, I will put this app in google play, do I need to have a User Id and private key for each user that downloads my app? Then I would have another table in my remote server with user_id and user_key for each one? This way I could protect my app, do you think it's necessary? Do you know any material, or website that would help me to learn the really professional side of Android programming? Thank you very much!

Comment: @etnishiyama, See this other answer with more details about security for an API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460878/api-based-on-user-ip-address/19461599#19461599 In case it wasn't clear, the app should call an API, and not connect to the database directly. Also, if any credentials or anything sensitive is being sent, use HTTPS. I'm actually on the iOS team where I work, not the Android team. I can tell you that they use IntelliJ IDEA community edition for their IDE.

Comment: @MarcusAdams How can I identify that particular record is updated or new record?

Comment: @ChiragParekh, you might have missed the following sentence. "Yes, a timestamp on each entry is used to determine which records are new/modified."

Comment: @MarcusAdams Yes I see that but how can I identify that from timestamp that which records is need to updated or which record is need to be inserted?

Comment: @ChiragParekh, If the last_sync_date from the client is NULL or older than the timestamp on a record, then the server sends that record.